# In OpenMediaVault, how do I secure an SMB share with login and password?

Tags: password, smb, nas

I'm running a NAS server with https://www.openmediavault.org/ on a Raspberry PI.
I've made a "shared folder", activated SMB sharing and within it created a share for this folder with "only guests" mode.
I can use the share over the network.

But now I want to secure it with a login/password instead of "only guests" and I'm a bit overwhelmed. How do I make sure my share needs credentials for access (read/write)?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it looks like I may have overlooked pressing `Apply configuration` during some of my experiments.
Assuming you have a share, which you can access in `Guests only` mode, the process for simple password-protected SMB share is like this:

- in `Access Rights Management` -> `User` create a new user, leave default groups. `Apply configuration`.
- in `Access Rights Management` -> `Shared Folders` choose the share, click `Privileges` at the top and give your new user Read\Write access. `Apply configuration`.
- in `Services` -> `SMB/CIFS` choose your share and switch its `Public` option from `Guests only` to `No`. `Apply configuration`.

Now when you try to login - you should be asked for credentials.